# Неявное преобразование типов данных int? в int в списке через базу данных

Tags: c#, entity-framework, database-first

Работаю с EntityFramework, подход - Database-First

Заранее создаю целочисленный список с верными ответами (берутся из БД) из таблицы Tests, из столбца Cor_Answer (с типом данных int), для более удобной работы и операциями над данными. Копирую в этот список значения из таблицы. Но тип данных становится int? и Visual Studio выдает ошибку: `Не удается неявно преобразовать тип System.Collections.Generic.List<int?> в System.Collections.Generic.List<int>`

```
static List<int> CorAnswer_List;

    using (Student_TestsNewEntities db = new Student_TestsNewEntities())
    {    
        var tests = db.Tests;
        CorAnswer_List = (from Tests in tests select Tests.Cor_Answer).ToList();
    }
```

**Вопрос**: как это починить, чтобы был тип данных int?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это означает, что поля в таблице могут содержать значения `NULL`, что соответствует `Nullable` целому.

```
CorAnswer_List = (from Tests in tests select Tests.Cor_Answer.Value).ToList();
```